# CSS Sprite Animation problem on Mobile Browser (residual image)

Tags: css, animation, mobile, sprite

Try the following link in any web browser on your desktop and then try it on any mobile browser (tried it on Android, iPhone & iPad - all produce same problem) and can someone tell me why the first 'frame' (well original sprite position) is always displayed behind the animation?

http://24hours-in.lincoln.ac.uk/projects/mus/animate2.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! (with a fudge)

```
var character = null; 
var xOffset = 0;

function animate() {
    if(xOffset < 360){
        xOffset += 30;
    } else {
        xOffset = 0;
    }
    character = document.getElementById("character");
    character.style.backgroundImage = "url('char2.png')";
    character.style.backgroundPosition = xOffset + "px 0px";
    setTimeout(animate,250);
}

function init() {
    var character = document.createElement("div");
    character.id = "character";
    character.style.backgroundImage = "url('spacer.png')";
    character.style.position = "absolute";
    character.style.width = "30px";
    character.style.height = "65px";
    document.getElementById("stage").appendChild(character);
    animate();
}

window.onload = init;
```

I figured it was using a background fallback of the original image because of the transparency.  Therefore, instead of starting off with the background image, I started off by applying a 1px transparent PNG file (abut assigning the rest of the CSS ready for the char PNG) and when it comes to the animation, I then substitute the background image to the char.PNG version.

I am sure there are more elegant ways, but this does the job!

Answer (score 0):

You know, to be honest, I don't know *what* causes the issue, but the issue is that the `character` background-image is static - that is to say, it's set in stone (via css).

A fix around your issue is to dynamically add the background-image using javascript. Here's your revised code.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#character {
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:65px;
    background-position: center center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var character = null; 
var xOffset = 0;

function animate() {
    if(xOffset < 360){
        xOffset += 30;
    } else {
        xOffset = 0;
    }
    character.style.backgroundImage = "url('char.png')";
    character.style.backgroundPosition = xOffset + 'px, 0px';
    setTimeout(animate,250);
}

function init() {
    character = document.getElementById("character");
    animate();
}

window.onload = init;

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="character"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Although what you're saying would make sense, it still hasn't resolved the issue.  If you check the link again you'll see there is still a residual of the initial position of the sprite.

Comment: It just seems strange that it's all mobile browsers.  I would understand if it was just one of them!

Comment: I have even made everything dynamic: http://24hours-in.lincoln.ac.uk/projects/mus/animate3.html and still the above problem occurs.  Maybe you're just not allowed to have transparent background images in mobile browsers :(

Comment: James - whoops! I had forgotten that I added a white background to the image. When I was testing it on my phone (on my server), that's why it worked. Is there a particular reason you can't have a background color for this image?

Comment: Yes, this is a sprite, and it will need to be overlaid on a background.  It's for a JS game I'm experimenting with for mobile devices.  But if their browsers don't support transparent backgrounds properly, then it's doomed!